# Как в WordPress отобразить на главной странице другую страницу?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот такая иерархия страниц

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы на Главной странице отображалась страница "Москва" ?

Comment: Вот больше бы информации - пока вопрос больше для гугла. Что и где вы меняли и что не получилось? В меню тоже нужно сделать правильные ссылки!

Answer (score 0):

Дайте статус "Главная страница" нужной вам странице.
Перейдите в меню "Настройки -> Чтение -> Главная страница" и выберите нужную страницу.

Comment: Так уже делал. Но когда перехожу на главную по меню то не отображается нужная мне страница "Москва"

Comment: @Denis ну так в меню пропиши нужную ссылку.

Comment: А это единственный способ? Задать произвольную ссылку с текстом "Главная" и прописать адрес скопировав из адресной строки? А внутреннюю страницу "Москва" сделать главной страницей?